# USB 100mA unit load average/rms or instantaneous

Tags: usb, low-power

I am attempting to understand the USB2 spec's definition of "unit load". It is clear that prior to enumeration one shouldn't draw a constant current of over 100mA. What is unclear is how this applies to pulsed current (as you might see from a switching converter for example). Is 100mA really a shorthand for the equivalent 500mW power?

In my application I'm sipping an average current below 5mA and every 2ms or so a switch opens and I have a current spike of about 200mA lasting about 2uS. Do these brief spikes violate the spec? Or am I good as long as the average (assuming a periodic power profile, bonus points for non-periodic use case) is below 100mA.

Comment: I would say it violates the spec but don't you have capacitors on the device to soak up that peak current? 200 mA for 2 us is a tiny capacitor.

Comment: as someone already mentioned below, the USB spec is clear about limiting the capacitance on the device side to 10uF.

Comment: Input side yes, but your say 3.3 Vcc after the LDO/buck is unlimited in size by the USB soecification. But yes, if you do straight Vcc from the 5 V input, you are limited.

Answer (score 3):

Since the other end has an over current protection circuit, I'll bet it's a hard and fast 100mA limit. If you have a pulsed current, you'll have to smooth out the power somehow otherwise you hit the limit (even if it is briefly) and your power will shut off. I'm not sure if there is a time limit in the spec, I'm not even going to check because its easy to overcome this problem.

The equation for sizing a cap to make sure you can ride this bump is:

$$C=I\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta V}$$
Where I is the current, t is the time of the event and V is the difference in voltage away from the rail.

So if you can only dip down to 4.9V then the \$ \Delta V\$ would be 0.1V.
and the cap would be

$$ C = 200mA \frac{2uS}{0.1V} = 4uF $$

So a 10uF cap would prevent a 0.05V drop and probably be sufficient.  You may ave to put a series inductor to prevent inrush current when the device is plugged in from the capacitors. This would also help filter spikes.

Comment: The USB spec only allows up to 10µF directly on the USB device power lines. Anything above that may cause problems on the host or hub side.